# How to foreach this kind of array using php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
array(1) {
      ["album_name"]=>
      string(12) "Cover Photos"
    }

    array(1) {
      ["cover"]=>
      string(111) "url"
    }

    array(1) {
      ["album_name"]=>
      string(24) "Fun in Your Name! Photos"
    }

    array(1) {
      ["cover"]=>
      string(108) "url"
    }
```

This is what it return when I do a `var_dump`to my variable, I tried a normal foreach:

```
<?php
foreach ($fb_albums as $my_albumsdata):
    echo $my_albumsdata['cover'];
endforeach;
?>
```

But doesn't work...

Comment: could you post the output of `var_dump($fb_albums);` just before your foreach loop?

Comment: `But doesn't work`: How helpful!!!

Comment: That's not an array, that's *four* arrays.

Comment: It seems to be not required foreach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($yourArray); $i += 2) {
    $name = $yourArray[$i]["album_name"]
    $cover = $yourArray[$i+1]["cover"] 
}
```

But, I think you must change the organisation of the Array.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have an array of those four arrays....
the problem would seem to be that not every $my_albumsdata contains a "cover".

`if(array_key_exists("cover", $my_albumsdata)) echo $my_albumsdata["cover"];`

^should be a quick fix, but lacking context, I'm not sure if this works for you.